# How to make Chrome to wait for dynamic li elements to get loaded in Ul with Watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Here "li" elements would display dynamically based on search results in page . so how could ask chrome browser to wait until all li elements get loaded before clicking on save

It is working fine in firefox , but i am getting this issue on chrome

```
<ul class="profile-section-list search-results-list">

all 'li' would get loaded dynamically


</ul>
```

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation: http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/EventuallyPresent

Comment: How would you know if they were all loaded? Is there a specific one or a certain number to expect?

Comment: it loads 20 items per search . so how could we do it , please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you expect a certain number to appear, you can wait for the last one to appear.

One option is to wait until the ul element has at least 20 li elements:

```
browser.wait_until do
  browser.ul(class: 'search-results-list').lis.length >= 20
end
```

Another option is to wait until the 20th li becomes present (note that this is a 0-based index):

```
browser.ul(class: 'search-results-list').li(index: 19).wait_until_present
```

Comment: Sorry , its not waiting for li list ,i think li list is getting loaded very fastly . thats why it is going for next event click

Comment: I've added text display validation by passing it dynamically for making it to wait  present